# Sweet Alert Shows success but record not deleted

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

**PHP code**

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get members");

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { // preparing an array

    $schoolID   = $row["schoolID"];
    $schoolname = $row["schoolname"];
    $program    = $row["program"];

    $nestedData = array();
    $nestedData[] = $row["schoolname"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["level"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["program"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["startdate"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["duration"];
    $nestedData[] = "   <a href='upDateSchool.php?schoolID=$schoolID' class='btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil'>
                        </a>
                            |           
                        <a class='btn  btn-danger' id='delete_school' data-id='<?php echo schoolID=$schoolID$schoolID; ?>',  href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></a>
                    ";
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).on('click', '#delete_school', function(e){

      var schoolID = $(this).data('id');
      SwalDelete(schoolID);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });

  function SwalDelete(schoolID){

    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "Record Deleted is Irreversible!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
      cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonText: "No!",
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,

      preConfirm: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {

           $.ajax({
            url: 'deleteSchool.php',
            type: 'post',
              data: 'delete='+schoolID,
              dataType: 'json'
           })
           .done(function(response){
            swal('Deleted!', response.message, response.status);
          readProducts();
           })
           .fail(function(){
            swal('Oops...', 'Something went wrong with ajax !', 'error');
           });
        });
        },
      allowOutsideClick: false        
    }); 

  }



</script>
```

PHP code for deleting

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$response = array();    

$sid = $_POST['delete'];
$query = "DELETE FROM school where schoolID=  :schoolID";
$stmt = $db->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute(array(':schoolID'=>$sid));

if ($stmt) {
    $response['status']  = 'success';
    $response['message'] = 'School Deleted Successfully ...';
} else {
    $response['status']  = 'error';
    $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete School ...';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

When I click the delete button, it shows response success but the record does is not deleted.

Comment: Did you tried to dump your $_POST or see POST data in Chrome Dev Console? Is $sid contains right integer?

Comment: for one thing, you're using the mysqli_ api in one code, then jumping to PDO after, *why?*

Comment: then you have this `<?php echo schoolID=$schoolID$schoolID;` which should be throwing you something about that. Your code failed on more than one level. Best you start checking for errors.

Comment: Then there's this `$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get members");` - I don't get that; what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I doubt I'll get a response so I'll just *"mosey along"* now.

Comment: yes I did but the value is not able to pass to the $sid variable

Comment: project is in mysqli but am converting them into PDO step by step thats why some of the code uses PDO and others still on mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains many logical and syntax problems, but still.
The problem is, that you exactly don't print out ID in `data-id` attribute.
Try to change this:

```
$nestedData[] = "   <a href='upDateSchool.php?schoolID=$schoolID' class='btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil'>
                    </a>
                        |           
                    <a class='btn  btn-danger' id='delete_school' data-id='<?php echo schoolID=$schoolID$schoolID; ?>',  href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></a>
                ";
```

To this:

```
$nestedData[] = "   <a href='upDateSchool.php?schoolID=".$schoolID."' class='btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil'>
                    </a>
                        |           
                    <a class='btn  btn-danger' id='delete_school' data-id='".$schoolID."',  href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></a>
                ";
```

It may help, but I recommend you to perform refactoring of your code.

Comment: thanks it worked now. The data gets deleted when I click the bottom. But I have to refresh the page to see the changes. How do I get to refresh the page and see the changes after the deleting

Comment: You can call `window.location.reload()` anywhere in your JS code.

Comment: thanks Abraham.. it worked. Do you know where I can get tutorials on php to PDF?

Comment: If it worked, accept answer.
You can find such tutorials in google with respective request.